# NUnit: The API to Check Whether Two Dictionaries Are the Same

Tags: c#, nunit

Given two dictionaries

```
var dictA = new Dictionary<string, classA>();
var dictB = new Dictionary<string, classA>();
```

How to check whether these two dictionaries are the same? **The catch here** is that I can't use the default `classA.Equals` for comparing the value pairs. Instead, the test will pass when and only when given that all the object of the `classA` type in the dictionaries must satisfy my own custom `IEqualityComparer<ClassA>`.

Specifically, I am looking at something like

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(dictA, dictB, new ClassEqualityComparer());
```

with `ClassEqualityComparer` inherits from  `IEqualityComparer<ClassA>`, or equivalent. I don't mind if I have to subclass a NUnit type of `IEqualityComparer` ( such as `IResolveConstraint`), but the most important thing is that the `Assert` method must be something like

```
Assertion(dictA, dictB, EqualityComparer)
```

Or something even more simpler; I don't want to use `Assert.That` and then implement a type of `IResolveConstraint` that runs into pages just to check whether two dictionaries are the same.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

So I guess you'll need to test that dictionary "B" contains all the same keys as "A" and vice versa, and then use your comparer to compare each value:

```
Assert.IsTrue(dictA.Keys.All(k => dictB.ContainsKey(k));
Assert.IsTrue(dictB.Keys.All(k => dictA.ContainsKey(k));

var cmp = new ClassEqualityComparer();
Assert.IsTrue(dictA.Keys.All(k => cmp.Equals(dictA[k], dictB[k]));
```

Will that work?

Comment: Matt, that will work; in fact I have my own version of code that does more or less the same thing. But I want something built-in. After all dictionary comparison should be common enough to warrant a place in NUnit, or no?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the instantiation of these dictionaries in your unit tests you may pass a [comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) to the appropriate [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx).

Comment: That `comparer` only compares between the key of the dictionary, it doesn't compare between the values.

Comment: If you want to compare values, a list would be more appropriate data type than a hashtable.

Comment: I can't because a list comparison would mean that I have to get the order of item right. In my comparison, the orders are not important.